# Changing ::before pseudo styles in Edge does not repaint visually update as expected

Tags: javascript, css, microsoft-edge

I have come across an odd issue with MS Edge, and hope someone had an insight or solution.

I am the changing the class name of a `<div>` element with JS to apply a new style when clicked.

The `div` elem has a default style that has uses a `::before` selector.

The style that is applied on click makes use of a `::before` pseudo selector with a different `content` property.

The issue I am seeing is that MS Edge will not consistently update/repaint the display to reflect the styles applied with the `content` property. I would expect the `0` to change to an `X` and back again with each subsequent click in the example below.

I have created a simple example here : https://jsfiddle.net/s4bs81of/7/

```js
var classActive = false;

function AddClass(Elem, className) {
  if (Elem) {
    if (!Elem.classList) {
      var Classes = className.split(' ');

      for (var i = 0; i < Classes.length; i++) {
        if (Classes[i] != '') {
          if (!Elem.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + Classes[i] + '(\\s|$)'))) {
            Elem.className += ' ' + Classes[i];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (className != '') {
        Elem.classList.add(className);
      }
    }
  }
}

function RemoveClass(Elem, className) {
  if (Elem) {
    if (!Elem.classList) {
      if (Elem.className) {
        var Classes = className.split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < Classes.length; i++) {
          if (Classes[i] != '') {
            var Reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + Classes[i] + '(\\s|$)');
            Elem.className = Elem.className.replace(Reg, '');
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (Elem.classList.contains(className) && className != '') {
        Elem.classList.remove(className);
      }
    }
  }
}

function clickChangeClass() {
  var Elem;

  if (Elem = document.getElementById('elemId')) {

    if (classActive) {
      RemoveClass(Elem, 'JourneySelected');
      AddClass(Elem, 'Journey');
    } else {
      AddClass(Elem, 'JourneySelected');
      RemoveClass(Elem, 'Journey');
    }

    classActive = !classActive;
  }
}

if (Elem = document.getElementById('elemId')) {
  Elem.onclick = clickChangeClass;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#elemId {}

.JourneyContainer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FDFDFD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 100%;
}

.JourneyContainer::before {
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.Journey {
  background: green;
}

.JourneySelected {
  background: red;
}

.Journey::before {
  content: "0";
}

.JourneySelected::before {
  content: "X";
}
```

```html
<div id="elemId" class="JourneyContainer Journey"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea **why** Edge is acting like this, but it boils down to the `display` type. Change it from `table` to `block` and the browser will redraw correctly:

```js
var classActive = false;

function AddClass(Elem, className) {
  if (Elem) {
    if (!Elem.classList) {
      var Classes = className.split(' ');

      for (var i = 0; i < Classes.length; i++) {
        if (Classes[i] != '') {
          if (!Elem.className.match(new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + Classes[i] + '(\\s|$)'))) {
            Elem.className += ' ' + Classes[i];
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (className != '') {
        Elem.classList.add(className);
      }
    }
  }
}

function RemoveClass(Elem, className) {
  if (Elem) {
    if (!Elem.classList) {
      if (Elem.className) {
        var Classes = className.split(' ');

        for (var i = 0; i < Classes.length; i++) {
          if (Classes[i] != '') {
            var Reg = new RegExp('(\\s|^)' + Classes[i] + '(\\s|$)');
            Elem.className = Elem.className.replace(Reg, '');
          }
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (Elem.classList.contains(className) && className != '') {
        Elem.classList.remove(className);
      }
    }
  }
}

function clickChangeClass() {
  var Elem;

  if (Elem = document.getElementById('elemId')) {

    if (classActive) {
      RemoveClass(Elem, 'JourneySelected');
      AddClass(Elem, 'Journey');
    } else {
      AddClass(Elem, 'JourneySelected');
      RemoveClass(Elem, 'Journey');
    }

    classActive = !classActive;
  }
}

if (Elem = document.getElementById('elemId')) {
  Elem.onclick = clickChangeClass;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#elemId {}

.JourneyContainer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 150px;
  background: #FDFDFD;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.JourneyContainer::before {
  content: "";
  top: 50%;
  left: 10px;
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.Journey {
  background: green;
}

.JourneySelected {
  background: red;
}

.Journey::before {
  content: "0";
}

.JourneySelected::before {
  content: "X";
}
```

```html
<div id="elemId" class="JourneyContainer Journey"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you for that Richard, that's an acceptable solution for me.
I'll refactor the real code to accommodate for this, thanks again!